# Downloading Numerical Vertex Edit plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I cannot find the Numerical Vertex edit plugin in QGIS 3.6.

How can I download it or what is instead of this plugin in 3.6 version?

Comment: this plugin does not to be available for QGIS 3

Answer (score 5):

You can numerically edit the vertices directly using the vertex tool.

1. Select the layer you wish to edit and place it into edit mode.
2. Activate the Vertex Tool from the digitizing toolbar (can be activated for all layers or just current layer).
3. Hover over the feature you wish to edit and **Right Click** to open the table of vertices for that feature.
4. You can then double click on any of the x y values in the table and manually change them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Vertex Tool can edit *all the layers* at once? How did I not know that?!